# Sql server rounding issue down to 2 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a problem getting my "Rounding to 2 decimal places" to behave as I would expect.
Try this trivial example

```
declare @num numeric (18,2)
declare @vat numeric (18,2)
set @num = 11729.83
set @vat = 1.14
select round(@num/@vat,2)
```

I am getting an answer of 10289.320000 but I should be getting 10289.33 . The full un rounded number is  10289.324561403508771929824561404 (unless my maths is completely off)

Comment: `10289.324` => `10289.32` 3rd digit after decimal point is 4 so it is rounded down

Comment: im sure i remember from highschool, th 6 causes the 5 to round up which causes the 4 to round up, and causes the 2 to round up

Comment: comment on downvote pls?

Comment: You remember wrong. Sure the 4 is rounded to 5 if rounding to 3 decimal places, but that does not carry forward when you round to two decimal places. You should not round to 3 decimal places before rounding to two. You should always start from the original most precise value when rounding. The value to the right is .0045614... etc, which is less than .005, so you round down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select cast(round(@num/@vat,3) as decimal(18,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Round can either return a value lower than the original, or a value upper than the original. In fact it returns the value closest to the original.

If you want to systematically round a number to its lower or upper value, you could then use FLOOR or CEILING (Thanks @GarethD for refreshing my memory on CEILING...)

```
select round(floor(100*@num/@vat)/100,2) -> lower value
select round(ceiling(100*@num/@vat)/100,2) -> upper value
```

Otherwise round will indeed return 10289.32 when the value is strictly lower than 10289.325 (which is the case here)

Comment: Surely you would use `CEILING` to round up?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting to a decimal:

```
select cast(round(@num / @vat, 2) as numeric(18, 2))
```

I advocate `round()` to be explicit about the conversion method.

Comment: Whether SQL Server rounds or truncates during conversions varies depending what you are converting to and from. If you are converting from numeric to numeric types then it will round. A quick example would be `SELECT CAST(1.235 AS DECIMAL(10, 2))`, which yields 1.24, rather than 1.23 which would be the truncated result. Although, I would actually still advocate using round, because the intention is much clearer than relying on someone knowing how cast/convert behaves with different data types.

Comment: @GarethD . . . You are so correct.  I didn't check using the tool; I looked in the documentation for `convert()`.  And, the first reference says that `convert()` does truncation . . . but that is for strings.  Arrghh.  Later, it says that numeric values are rounded, just as you say. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @num numeric (18,2)
declare @vat numeric (18,2)
set @num = 11729.83
set @vat = 1.14
select round(Convert(Decimal(18,3),(@num/@vat)),2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand correctly. But maybe you've been looking for something like this:

```
select  round(round(round(round(@num / @vat, 5), 4), 3), 2)
```

Comment: requirement is different

Answer (score -1):

You will need to convert it to the appropriate decimal type again:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), ROUND(@NUM/@VAT,2))
```